# Using cvApproxPoly() on the results of cvConvexHull2() in OpenCV

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, convex-hull

I'm writing C (*not* C++) code to run convex hull on contours of rectangles. The (greatly simplified) code for that looks like this:

```
CvSeq* contours;
CvSeq* hull;

cvFindContours( img, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, CvPoint(0,0) );
hull = cvConvexHull2( contours, storage, CV_CLOCKWISE, 0 );
```

Where `img` and `contours` are both valid. There is a lot more between these lines, but the FindContours portion of it has been tested to work.

This code throws exception: **Error: Bad argument (Unsupported sequence type) in cvApproxPoly**.

I'm [told](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/54741) that the problem is that the flag that identifies the sequence as a polyline is not set, and I have tried the suggestion `hull->flags = hull->flags | 512` but presumably the flags have changed sometime between 2008 and now, since that does not work.

So the question is: how do I use cvApproxPoly() on the results of a cvConvexHull2()? What data type should I use, and what are the proper arguments for cvApproxPoly()?

Comment: `cvFindContours` has incorrect arguments. Show us full, actual calls to those three functions that produce this error.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing the storage parameter:

```
cvFindContours(<CvArr *image>, <CvMemStorage *storage>, <CvSeq **first_contour>, <int header_size>, <int mode>, <int method>, <CvPoint offset>)
```

Test using

```
CvMemStorage *storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
cvFindContours( img, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, CvPoint(0,0) );
hull = cvConvexHull2( contours, storage, CV_CLOCKWISE, 0 );
```